# Database for android login activity

Tags: android, authentication

I am new to android development and i am working with a login activity. So for that i need to create a central database so that all the users can be authenticated and hence logged in. So please tell me how can I do this.
Can I use sqlite to create this type of data or it is just used to create a local database per client? 
Thank you

Comment: Central database means a database in server.it is the better way to make a login Activity.you can use rest web service to do that

Comment: so how should i provide the address of this database kept at my server?

Comment: you can create API with php/java and upload to your server.then access it via its URL.you cant post your username and password in http post.the server gives a response in JSON/XML format.that response can be parsed and display as status.

Comment: @DivyeshJindal for some reason, my old answer (you accepted before) had deleted, you can accept it now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For allowing multiple user loggin in the app you need to use central database .

Below is the link which will help you a lot.

> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need an API to do this if you want it to span across several users. I'd recommend using Parse as a beginner as it's easy to set up and use.

https://www.parse.com/

tutorial:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

used a SQL database instead of sqlite and used sheared preference for local storage. that is the best for create a login activity in any application.

Comment: THank you
can you tell me how can i implement this?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ use this tutorial for create an API by using PHP  and passs that  api url in your code.as done ame in  tutorial. that is a best working tutorial

Comment: sure.. i added sheared preference class too in one more comment here.. if u face any problem feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

If you have the **Central Database** in the **Server** then simply use the 
**SharedPreferences** to save login credentials which you getting from Server for individual client device. No need to make the database for it.

Case2:

If you want to make **Central Database** in the **mobile** then use the **Sqlite** to save login credentials.

Comment: i am thinking of case 1. But i don't know how to communicate between the server and my app can u get me some help over that?

Comment: also how can i implement case 2. i.e central database in mobile because if the data is in the device of a particular device and if the user uninstalls the app all his records would vanish and the next time he downloads the app he has to signup again instead of just login in ?

Comment: First learn case 1. that is easy read this link [How can I fetch data from a web server in an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545378/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-web-server-in-an-android-application)

Comment: Thank you..i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

for sheared prefrence create a class name Session?Manager

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_api = "apikey";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";
    private static final String push_ = "AndroidHivePref";
    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;
    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    // Context
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void createLoginSession(String name, String apikey) {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);


        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_api, apikey);


        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int getMerchentPushCount() {
        return pref.getInt("MerchentPushCount", 0);
    }

    public void setMerchentPushCount(Integer count) {
        editor.putInt("MerchentPushCount", count);

        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();


        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        // user api key
        user.put(KEY_api, pref.getString(KEY_api, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }


    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |

                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * *
     */
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }


}
```

and called it in LoginActivity class ...

```
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences pref = session.pref;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at using [PHP with MySQL.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

for auto login, I recommend you to keep session in preference other than keeping user id and password.