# Sending data from sever to Android Device

Tags: php, android, lamp

I am using LAMP stack in my server and I want to send data from the server to the android device. The android device should not make a request to the server for getting the data , the server will send the data on its own and the android device should receive it using a background service. What should I do?

P.S -> I know GCM and parse.com do this using push notifications but is there any other way?

Comment: Make a background service which will ask data to the server and get it with JSON/XML ?

Comment: There may be ways other than GCM push notifications. Why do you want another way though - why is GCM not a solution for you?

Comment: @Mohit did you find any other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General I can see only three options,

1. Make time to time [requests from device to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545378/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-web-server-in-an-android-application)
2. Use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/)
3. Use a [signal R client for android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9ih_M7PC10) (if you need to use signalR you should use microsoft asp.net instead of LAMP )

I would like to recommend you GCM way. I haven't use Signal R in android native mobile applications but i have use it in web application development.
I have added some links above, hope it will help you.

Comment: If You satisfied with this answer, you can mark it as the correct answer @MohitBadwal