# android app development with live content fetching

Tags: android, server, instagram, social-networking

I am interested in making android app like crickbuzz that will fetch live content from server and also there is option of like and comment for users for feedback. So, can anyone tell that how to implement this i.e (how to fetch data from server) how that data will fit in app(confused about this how data get fit in instagram app means profile, home, search tab)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check out this links

[Android, PHP & MySQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm)

[Fetch Data From Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545378/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-web-server-in-an-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's break it down:

The data is obtained from the server using http requests. It is usually received in the form of JSON String, basically a ordered, human-readable data format which is easy to read and parse.

On the app side, you need to implement the layout, which is done in xml and Java. You also need some logic which will obtain the data with the aforementioned requests, parse it, turn into Java Objects and put everything into the layout.

The process is not really complex, could be completed by a single person, but you will need **experience, time and good architectural decisions**.

If this is your first time with Android app programming, do some tutorials (especially ones that cover networking), learn some libraries (Volley, Retrofit, org.json, RXJava, Picasso will be really useful for what you ask about) and code several small apps from start to end. After that you may be ready to tackle the app you described :-)

Comment: Thank you Kelevandos for your answer, but there is a request for you, can you suggest me any tutorial which cover networking, actually I surfed alot but didn't find any tutorial which helps me.

Comment: Here you will find a quick tutorial which should give you an idea on how Volley works :-) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800