# Fetch data from a dynamic website in Android

Tags: php, android

I want to access and display data from a website which is like a notice board, i.e, data content keeps getting updated at irregular intervals. Whenever any new content is updated I want the user to get a notification. The content updated might have links which I want to include in my app.

Initially I have to login to the access the data on which I found several satisfactory tutorials. The website is `php` based([link](http://kiittnp.in/tnp/usr/index.php)). How can I retrieve this data with minimal delay and in a readable format?

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545378/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-web-server-in-an-android-application).