# How to get Data for your app from your Server?

Tags: java, android, database, api, server

So I want to know the basic idea of how a app can get its data from your own server. We use APIs to get data from other data sources like OpenWeather . But now if we want to create our own source how would you do that? I just want to know the basic idea not the code.

Thanks

Comment: Learn about the wonders of HTTP.

Comment: Adding to the above comment: also learn about the wonders of RESTful api.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545378/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-web-server-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea would be:

1. get a free hosting somewhere (there's a lot of PHP hosting websites with MySQL)
2. create a simple [REST](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) [API](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)
3. get some data into your database (create a simple CMS to add data to the DB)
4. make your Android app call your website just like you did with the weather API

TL;DR: create your own API